# Git Hanging Response Killed

Tags: git, centos

When I run a git commit or git status I am getting a response of killed.

```
git commit -am 'added images'
Killed
```

After a .git/index.lock file is generated, I can delete the lock file and try again but I keep getting the response Killed.

Comment: How quickly does it die? If you don't pass a message on the command line do you get an editor spawning? If you do does it still die after you save and quit the editor? Are you adding a very large amount of image data?

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by doing a commit while I was using Vagrant in SSH but having the repo initially set up on my Mac. Basically I missed the fact that I had the exact same .git directory on two systems because of Vagrant.